# PyQGIS standalone app processing with selectbylocation not working

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, select-by-location, standalone

I'm trying to run processing with `selectbylocation` in standalone app, everything seems to run fine but the output I'm getting is the main layer always, so it's not really working. And I have no idea how to make it raise an error.

```
def select_by_location(main_layer, chosen_layer):

    parameters = {
        "INPUT": main_layer,
        "INTERSECT": chosen_layer,
        "METHOD": 0,
        "PREDICATE": [0],
        "OUTPUT": "TEMPORARY_OUTPUT",
    }
    result = processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:selectbylocation", parameters)['OUTPUT']
    return result
    
qgs = core.QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
Processing.initialize()
result = select_by_location(main_layer, layer)
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'test_new')
core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(result, path, "UTF-8", driverName="GPKG")
qgs.exitQgis()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by changing the algorithm to "Extract by location" and for feedback found:

```
 feedback = core.QgsProcessingFeedback()
```

as well as keep in mind that the location you initialize processing in your code is important.